# Which input attribute does for attribute work with?

Tags: forms, input

According to what I have studied, the for attribute in label tag is used to relate that label with a particular input. In order to do so, I understand the input tag has to have an attribute which should have the same value that the for attribute of the label tag has. However, I am not so sure about what attribute is to be used in the input tag in order to accomplish this. 
So far I believed the for attribute of label tag was coordinating with id attribute of input tag. I have read, though, that the id attribute is just for style purposes. So, I guess this discards this options.

In the example below, **how could I then accomplish to generate a coordination between the label tag and the input tag?**

```
<label for="dinosaur">Name your favorite dinosaur:</label>
<input type="text" id="dinosaur" name="dinosaur">
```

Is the name attribute responsible for the coordination with the for attribute?

Comment: The attribute of input is id which is matched to label for

Comment: @zer00ne, so is it false the statement that I have read somewhere else that the id attribute is just used for stylish purposes?

Comment: Technically, no it's not false...just misleading. An id like any other attribute of an element may be used as a selector. A selector is a string that identifies elements by their traits: ex. id: `"#X"`, class: `".X"`, name: `"[name='X']"`, tag: `"div"`, etc. A selector can be used in CSS to assign styles or used to locate and access an element(s) in the DOM.  BTW there is a very important limitation in the use of an #id: ***#ID must be unique -- it is invalid to have more than one element on the same page sharing the same #ID***. The other attributes do not have that limitation.